# fs2: How to do something once the stream is started ("doOnSubscribe")?

Tags: scala, cats-effect, fs2

I am trying to use an impure ("java") API in the context of a cats-effect IO-App. The impure API looks somewhat like this:

```
import  io.reactivex.Flowable
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

trait ImpureProducer[A] {
  /** the produced output - must be subscribed to before calling startProducing() */
  def output: Flowable[A]

  /** Makes the producer start publishing its output to any subscribers of `output`. */
  def startProducing(): CompletableFuture[Unit]
}
```

(Of course, there are more methods including stopProducing(), but those are not relevant for my question.)

My (maybe naive) approach to adapt that API looks as follows (leveraging the fact that `Flowable` is a `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`):

```
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.interop.reactivestreams.*

class AdaptedProducer[A](private val underlying: ImpureProducer[A]) {
  def output: Stream[IO, A] =
    underlying.output.toStreamBuffered(1)
  def startProducing: IO[Unit] = 
    IO.fromCompletableFuture(IO(underlying.startProducing()))
}
```

My question is: **how can I ensure that the `output`-stream is subscribed to before I evaluate `startProducing`?**

For example, how could I fix the following attempt to obtain an IO of the very first item that is produced:

```
import cats.Parallel
import cats.effect.IO

def firstOutput[A](producer: AdaptedProducer[A]): IO[A] = {
  val firstOut: IO[A] = producer.output.take(1).compile.onlyOrError
  // this introduces a race condition: it is not ensured that the output-stream
  // will already be subscribed to when startProducing is evaluated.
  Parallel[IO].parProductL(firstOut)(producer.startProducing)
}
```

Comment: I will write a complete answer latter today, but you want to use the new `flow` interop: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-docs_2.13/3.9.3/fs2/interop/flow/index.html there is a `fromPublisher` overload that allows you to run something before / after calling `subscribe`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that pointer should already be enough for me to figure it out, but if you have time to write an answer, I'd nevertheless appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the new **Java** `flow` interop.
Note that the **reactive-streams** inteop is *deprecated* since the addition of the `flow` one.
The API was redesigned to handle more cases *(like this one)* and the implementation was re-done from scratch to be more efficient.
If the API you are using doesn't have a `flow` based version, you can use the [`FlowAdapters`](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.4-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/FlowAdapters.html) to wrap it.

The code would look like this:

```scala
import org.reactivestreams.FlowAdapters

final class AdaptedProducer[A](underlying: ImpureProducer[A], chunkSize: Int) {
  val run: Stream[IO, A] =
    fs2.interop.flow.fromPublisher(chunkSize) { subscriber =>
       IO(
         underlying.output.subscribe(
            FlowAdapters.toFlowSubscriber(
             subscriber
            )
         )
       ) >>
       IO.fromCompletableFuture(IO(underlying.startProducing()))
    }    
}
```

This ensures that `startProducing` is called only when you actually start consuming the `Stream` and after have called `subscribe`.

Hope this helps :D